Is it possible to sum separate rows where value exists in separate column in SQL?
This is my desired result where I would like ID = '00-456' to sum any ID row's Quantity where it is present in the Alt_ID column as well as the ID column:



ID
Alt_ID
Quantity
Total




00-123
00-456
10
10


00-456
NULL
5
15



This is a snippet of my current query, but I am unable to get the Alt_ID row to SUM with the ID column where applicable
SELECT
    ID,
    Alt_ID,
    Quantity,
    CASE
        WHEN Alt_ID != ''
            THEN Total_Usage
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT T2.Alt_ID
                     FROM dbo.Table AS T2
                     WHERE T2.Alt_ID = T1.ID)
            THEN SUM(Total_Usage) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID, T1.Alt_ID)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Total
FROM
    dbo.Table AS T1

This query returns:



ID
Alt_ID
Quantity
Total




00-123
00-456
10
10


00-456
NULL
5
5



Any help is appreciated

Alt_ID != '' is not the same as Alt_ID IS NOT NULL...

Please make clear what the raw data is and exactly what the result should be.

Please provide example dboTotal table design and records. where does Total_Usage come from?

Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See this to know why tagging is important.

BTW, perhaps don't even allow empty strings in Alt_ID. Consider a check constraint.

sum(Quantity) over (partition by coalesce(Alt_ID, ID)) ?

try SUM with a CASE statement and a LEFT JOIN to aggregate the quantities:
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    T1.Alt_ID,
    T1.Quantity,
    COALESCE(SUM(T2.Quantity), T1.Quantity) AS Total
FROM
    dbo.Table AS T1
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Table AS T2
ON
    T1.ID = T2.ID OR T1.ID = T2.Alt_ID
GROUP BY
    T1.ID,
    T1.Alt_ID,
    T1.Quantity

output:



ID
Alt_ID
Quantity
Total




00-123
00-456
10
10


00-456
NULL
5
15



